# Optimistic record locking in CakePHP

Tags: model, cakephp-2.0, behavior, optimistic-locking

I've started playing with CakePHP and I'm trying to set up some optimistic locking on records which I find isn't in the core. In the Apress book **Practical CakePHP** Projects there's an example that creates optimistic locking in a behaviour using a "lock" field. This is written for CakePHP 1.2 and I'm using 2.0, I was also hoping to use the the "modified" field instead rather than a separate field for locked.

What I planned to do was look at the modified date in the retrieved record and then in a **beforeValidate** function to compare this to what's in the database. If its different then someone else has access the record so generate an exception.

The function I have is

```
function beforeValidate(&$model) {
    // First find the record
    if (isset($model->data[$model->name]['id']) ){
        $id = $model->data[$model->name]['id'];
        $table = $model->table;
        $currentRecord = $model->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));

        if(!empty($currentRecord)) {
            if($model->data[$model->name]['modified'] != $currentRecord[0][$table]['modified']) {
                $model->validationErrors['modified'] = 'Update conflict, another user has already updated the record. Please list and edit the record again.';
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

What I've found is when I try to run this I get the following error

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: modified [APP/Model/Behavior/MagicFieldsPlusBehavior.php, line 21]
Notice (8): Undefined index: schools [APP/Model/Behavior/MagicFieldsPlusBehavior.php, line 21]
```

"schools" being the table and "modified" the field - yes they're present :-)

The line 21 is

```
if($model->data[$model->name]['modified'] != $currentRecord[0][$table]['modified']) {
```

Thanks in advance for help debugging a newbie's mistakes!

Brian